# HIve insert statement taking too long

Tags: apache, hive, orc

I have 200 Insert statements in a single file (test.hql) to insert them to a ORC format hive table.Each insert takes significant time(40 secs) making the complete process to take close to 2 hours. Is there way to speed things up ?

I could have created a tmp (text format) table and then do simple insert overwrite but that is not allowed.. I cannot create new DDLs..
-> One option is to break the test.hql in shell and execute in parallel processes. 
Is there any other way I can make these inserts fast in Hive itself ??

Answer (score 0):

Many insert statements are slower than single one. Transform your 200 inserts into single one using UNION ALL:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)] 
select value1 as col1, value2 as col2... coln from default.dual union all
select value1 as col1, value2 as col2... coln from default.dual union all
...
select value1 as col1, value2 as col2... coln from default.dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can create a input file and load into table at once.

Create table with particular row format(with delimiters)

Create table test (a string, b string) row format fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

And then load data into it,

LOAD DATA inpath "/path" into table table_name;

Comment: Yes already did that - But cannot create DDLs now, Kindof project requirement

Comment: Each insert will start a new mapreduce job, that is why it is taking too much time. may be switching the execution engine to spark will reduce time. Try that. If you are using cloudera you can change the execution engine.